# How to replace some elements of a matrix by other numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, replace, binary

I have a matrix consists of 1000 binary elements like below in Matlab:

> M = [011,011,001,010,011,000,010,100,100,...,...]

I want to replace some elements by other numbers: 000 By 000000, 110 By 000001, 001 By 00001, 100 By 0001, 101 By 001, 010 By 01, 011 By 1.

I used this method but doesn't work. What is wrong with it?

```
for i = 1:1000
    if M(i) == 000
        M(i) = 000000;
    elseif M(i) == 110
         M(i) = 000001;
         elseif M(i) == 001
               M(i) = 00001;
               elseif M(i) == 100
                 M(i) = 0001;   
                 elseif M(i) == 101
                 M(i) = 001; 
                 elseif M(i) == 010
                 M(i) = 01;
    else
         M(i) = 1;
    end
end
```

Please help me:)

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What is the problem you're having? does it not replace the desired values? or does it do incorrect replacements?

Comment: it doesn't replace the values

Comment: In MATLAB literal numbers like `000` and `001` are interpreted as floating point decimal numbers. The equality operator (`==`) checks if the values of these numbers are the same, so an expression like `000 == 000000` is basically checking if zero equals zero, which it does. The same applies to assignment (`=`), so `if M(i) == 000; M(i) = 000000; end` is saying if `M(i)` equals zero, then assign zero to `M(i)`, which isn't doing anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i can replace some elements of a matrix by other numbers in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235315/how-i-can-replace-some-elements-of-a-matrix-by-other-numbers-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in matlab, when you type `000` it means number `0`. If you want to express it as `000`, one way to do that is by using string `'000'`.

I am going to build a look up chart first.

```
    Lookup_In  = [  000      110      001    100    101  010  011 ] ;
    Lookup_Out = {'000000','000001','00001','0001','101','01','1' } ;
```

Then, build a space for the answer, StrOut. M is the original input.

```
    M = [011,011,001,010,011,000,010,100,100] ;        
    StrOut = repmat({'Unknown'},size(M)) ;
```

Check if the element in M can find in lookup table `Lookup_In`.

```
    [tf, idx] =ismember(M, Lookup_In) ;
```

Output the final result.

```
    StrOut(tf) = Lookup_Out(idx(tf))
```

Then, you will get

```
     '1'    '1'    '00001'    '01'    '1'    '000000'    '01'    '0001'    '0001'
```