# How can i replace some elements of a matrix by other numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, binary

I have a matrix consists of 1000 binary elements like below in Matlab:

> M = 
>   11001100101100001011010001001100101000101110010110001‌​10000101010110010111‌​0111001...

How i can split every 3 elements and replace them By another elements. for example `000 By 000000`, `110 By 000001`, `001 By 00001`, `100 By 0001`, `101 By 001`, `010 By 01`, `011 By 1`.

I used this method but it doesn't work. What is wrong with it?

```
  Lookup_In  = [  000      110      001    100    101  010  011 ] ;
  Lookup_Out = {'000000','000001','00001','0001','101','01','1' } ;
  StrOut = repmat({'Unknown'},size(M)) ;
  [tf, idx] =ismember(M, Lookup_In) ;
  StrOut(tf) = Lookup_Out(idx(tf))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i can encode some elements in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235922/how-i-can-encode-some-elements-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

`M` here is randomly generated with `1000` binary elements:

```
rng(1);
M = randi([0 1], 1,1000);
fprintf('%d\n',M)
```

First, I zeropadded `M` to reach a length multiple of 3. Second, I reshaped the array in a matrix with 3 elements of each row and applied `Lookup_Out`.

```
c = mod(numel(M),3);
M = [M,zeros(1,3-c)]; %zeropadding to multiple of 3

M = reshape(M,[3,numel(M)/3])';

Lookup_In  = [  000      110      001    100    101  010  011 ] ;
Lookup_Out = {'000000','000001','00001','0001','101','01','1' } ;
StrOut = repmat({''},[1,size(M,1)]);

for r=1:size(M,1)
    StrOut{r} = Lookup_Out{str2double(sprintf('%d',M(r,:))) == Lookup_In};
end
```

Comment: thank you. but i have a matrix like this : M = 0011101010100011010111000100100100100000 .... first i want to split each 3 elements for example : 001, 110, 101, 010, .... then replace each 3 elements By another elements. for example 000 By 000000, 110 By 000001 , ...

Comment: M = 0011101010100011010111000100100100100000 is a number starting with 00, so M = 11101010100011010111000100100100100000. I assume you can consider M like a string, M = '0011101010100011010111000100100100100000'?
You can convert it to a numeric array using M = str2num(M(:))';

Comment: M is a binary matrix

Comment: To avoid ambiguities, can you provide `M` as displayed by MATLAB in the command window?

Comment: M =

01101101001011001110010001010010010010001110100110110001011010001001100100101101101100110001001101001001110001110110001010010010000...  I'm new with English language. I hope i understand you correctly:)

Comment: Do you agree that `M` is not a matrix, only a number? `size(M)` returns `[1 1] ` and `M = 01101101001011001110010001010010010010001110100110110001011010001001100100101101101100110001001101001001110001110110001010010010000` is equal to `M = 1101101001011001110010001010010010010001110100110110001011010001001100100101101101100110001001101001001110001110110001010010010000`

Comment: this is all my code:clear;
clc;
a=0;
b=3;
A=round(a+(b-a)*rand(1,1000));
B=round(a+(b-a)*rand(1,1000));
SUM =  A + B;
DecSum = dec2bin(SUM);
s = 1;
for i = 1:1000
    for j = 1:3
        M(1,s) = DecSum(i,j);
        s = s+1;
    end
end
Tr = sum(diff(M)~=0); I made two random numbers. then i add every two bits. now the answer is in M.

Comment: @user3637733 You could modify the question and include this code, but I've done all the possible to solve the problem.